# Divert logs with syslog.conf and asl.conf

Tags: logging

I have made several attempts to use syslog.conf and asl.conf to divert all Firefox logs to its own log file on OS X 10.6.8.

The only things that has partially worked so far is the following entry in asl.conf:

```
? [= Sender firefox] ignore
```

This removes most Firefox logs from 'All Messages' and 'Console Messages' but not from 'system.log'.

I have not yet discovered a satisfactory way to:

1 - Put Firefox logs in /var/log/firefox.log

2 - Remove Firefox logs from system.log

3 - Exclude all Firefox logs from 'All Messages' and 'Console Messages'

I am not sure if my problems are related to Apple's gradual move from syslog.conf to asl.conf or my lack of experience of using these config files.

My reason for wanting to do this is that the latest satisfactory browser for my OS is the no longer supported Firefox 45.9.0 ESR which is very chatty and pollutes my log files with hundreds of entries per day from trivial CSS issues to unnecessary memory leak scares.

All my attempts to use syslog.conf have failed. The one setting which puts Firefox logs in the correct place also puts most other logs there as well.

I have not found any way to reduce entries in system.log.

The following is an example of logs which still appear in 'All Messages' and 'Console Messages' despite the 'Sender firefox] ignore' entry in asl.conf:

```
17/02/2019 16:29:29   [0x0-0xf00f].org.mozilla.firefox[250]   com.apple.console   Notice   2019-02-17 16:29:29.584 crashreporter[323:903] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x1001115a0 of class NSPathStore2 autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
```

Here is my syslog.conf file:

```
*.notice;authpriv,remoteauth,ftp,install,internal.none  /var/log/system.log
kern.*                      /var/log/kernel.log

# Send messages normally sent to the console also to the serial port.
# To stop messages from being sent out the serial port, comment out this line.
#*.err;kern.*;auth.notice;authpriv,remoteauth.none;mail.crit        /dev/tty.serial

# The authpriv log file should be restricted access; these
# messages shouldn't go to terminals or publically-readable
# files.
auth.info;authpriv.*;remoteauth.crit    /var/log/secure.log

lpr.info                        /var/log/lpr.log
mail.*                      /var/log/mail.log
ftp.*                       /var/log/ftp.log
install.*                       /var/log/install.log
install.*                       @127.0.0.1:32376
local0.*                        /var/log/appfirewall.log
local1.*                        /var/log/ipfw.log

*.emerg                     *
```

Here is my asl.conf file:

```
##
# configuration file for syslogd and aslmanager
##

? [= Sender firefox] ignore

# redirect com.apple.message.domain to /var/log/DiagnosticMessages
? [T com.apple.message.domain] store_dir /var/log/DiagnosticMessages exclude_asldb

# authpriv messages are root/admin readable
? [= Facility authpriv] access 0 80

# remoteauth critical, alert, and emergency messages are root/admin readable
? [= Facility remoteauth] [<= Level critical] access 0 80

# broadcast emergency messages
? [= Level emergency] broadcast

# save kernel [PID 0] and launchd [PID 1] messages
? [<= PID 1] store

# save everything from emergency to notice
? [<= Level notice] store

# save lpr info level and above
? [<= Level info] [= Facility lpr] store

# save all mail, ftp, local0, and local1 messages
? [= Facility mail] store
? [= Facility ftp] store
? [= Facility local0] store
? [= Facility local1] store
```

Any assistance or insights would be much appreciated.